# HTML javascript movie and dinner

Tags: javascript, html

I'm receiving NotANumber for my total from movieTotal, as well as im not getting the correct value of adding pricePerTicket + pricePerDinner. Can someone help me figure out what im doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var ticket, earlyBirdTicket, WeekDinner, weekendDinner, numberOfTickets, TotalDue;
var numberOfTickets, pricePerTicket, pricePerDinner, costOfDandT, totalAmountOwed;
var totalDandT, yes, week, movieTotal;
var ticket = 5;
var nightTicket = 10;
var weekDinner = 8;
var weekendDinner = 12;
var yes = ticket;
var week = weekDinner;
var movieTotal = totalDandT * numberOfTickets; 
totalDandT = pricePerDinner + pricePerTicket;
numberOfTickets = prompt ("How many tickets?");
pricePerTicket = prompt ("Is this earlybird? yes/no ");
pricePerDinner = prompt ("weekend or weekday? week/weekend ");
pricePerTicket = parseInt(pricePerTicket);
pricePerDinner = parseInt(pricePerDinner);
movieTotal = parseInt (movieTotal);
if (pricePerTicket = yes)
{
     pricePerTicket = ticket;
}
else
{
     pricePerTicket = nightTicket;
}
if (pricePerDinner = week)
{
     pricePerDinner = weekDinner;
}
else
{
     pricePerDinner = weekendDinner;
}
document.write ("<br>Number of tickets sold : " + numberOfTickets);
document.write ("<br>Cost per ticket tonight : $" + pricePerTicket);
document.write ("<br>Cost per dinner tonight : $" + pricePerDinner);
document.write ("<br>Cost of dinner and ticket : $" + pricePerTicket + pricePerDinner);
document.write ("<br> Your total today is $" + movieTotal);
// -->
</script>
```

Comment: I tried switching those 2 and i still get the same response

Comment: thank you sooo much. i was putting my parseints way before i initialized. thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized the variables. You should do it before using them.
Uninitialized variables are equals to *undefined* so yes.undefined plus undefined is not a number.